# Merge audio from soundcloud with video file and store on our server? Violation of the api?

Tags: audio, video, merge, soundcloud

Im currently using the SoundCloud API to stream music. My service allows people to add tracks from soundcloud to their videos uploaded to our service.

At the moment i have to do two calls, one call to the server for the video file and one call for the audio stored on SoundClouds servers. Is is possible for me to merge the sound from
SoundCloud into the video file hosted on our server or is this a violation of the API?

I have sent 4 emails to different accounts of soundclouds support without result.

Comment: You mentioned you sent emails to 4 different soundcloud accounts. Just wanted to make sure, did  you sent a mail through [help.soundcloud.com](http://help.soundcloud.com) as well?

Comment: Hi Marco, no i havent, ill have a look there too. Thanks!

Comment: Sent another response to their legal department, will keep this thread updated as i go forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That probably depends on the license of the individual tracks on SoundCloud, I'm no lawyer, but I think if the tracks have a suited creative commons license and allow downloads it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: You might be right there.. i see they have a function for it... 

 "downloadable": true,
 "download_url": "http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/13158665/download",

Still i would like to hear what SoundCloud says about this since its doable for me to do what im trying to achieve, just not sure its within their EULA.